# 4 FIFO and serialization

Tags: vhdl, fifo

I have implemented a 4 FIFO Queue and a block that searches for FIFO index and when found a FIFO that is not empty will extract data end, it will send it serially.

This is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Serialize is
       port
       (
           TX                                                                  : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
           RESET, CLK, We1, We2, We3, We4                                      : in std_logic;
           --
           DATA_IN_A, DATA_IN_B, DATA_IN_C, DATA_IN_D                          : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
           fifo_full1, fifo_full2, fifo_full3, fifo_full4                      : out std_logic;
           --
           SendPackage                                                         : out std_logic
       );
end Serialize;

architecture rtl of Serialize is
     signal step, nr : integer:=0;
     signal enl : std_logic := '0';
     signal temp : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     --signal txx  : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     TYPE sr_length IS ARRAY (0 to 3) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
     SIGNAL queue, queue1, queue2, queue3 : sr_length;
     signal ptr, ptr1, ptr2, ptr3 : integer:= 0;
    -- signal tmp : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     signal i_a, i_b : std_logic;
     signal q_a, q_b, q_c, q_d : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     --signal nr : integer := 0;
begin

     process(CLK, RESET, We1, We2, We3, We4, DATA_IN_A, DATA_IN_B, DATA_IN_C, DATA_IN_D) is
          --variable step, nr : integer:=0;
          --variable enl : std_logic := '0';
          --variable temp : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     begin
          if(RESET = '1') then
              SendPackage <= '0';
              TX<= "00";
             -- busy <= '0';
              --step:= 0;
              --temp := X"00000000";
              --enl := '0';
              step<= 1;
              temp <= X"00000000";
              enl <= '0';
               ptr <= 0;
               ptr1 <= 0;
               ptr2 <= 0;
               ptr3 <= 0;
               fifo_full1 <= '0';
               fifo_full2 <= '0';
               fifo_full3 <= '0';
               fifo_full4 <= '0';
               --nr := 0;
               nr <= 0;
               for i in 0 to 2 loop
                   queue(i)<=X"00000000";
                   queue1(i)<=X"00000000";
                   queue2(i)<=X"00000000";
                   queue3(i)<=X"00000000";
               end loop;
          end if;
          if(CLK'event) then
            if(CLK = '1')then
              --SendPackage <= '0';
            if(We1 = '1' or We2 = '1' or We3 = '1' or We4 = '1')then
               IF (We1 = '1' and ptr <= 3) THEN
                    for i in 0 to 2 loop
                        queue(i + 1) <= queue(i);
                    end loop;
                    queue(0) <= DATA_IN_A;
                    ptr <= ptr+ 1;
              END IF;
              IF (We2 = '1' and ptr1 <= 3) THEN
                    for i in 0 to 2 loop
                        queue1(i + 1) <= queue1(i);
                    end loop;
                    queue1(0) <= DATA_IN_B;
                    ptr1 <= ptr1+ 1;
              END IF;
              IF (We3 = '1' and ptr2 <= 3) THEN
                    for i in 0 to 2 loop
                        queue2(i + 1) <= queue2(i);
                    end loop;
                    queue2(0) <= DATA_IN_C;
                    ptr2 <= ptr2 + 1;
              END IF;
              IF (We4 = '1' and ptr3 <= 3) THEN
                    for i in 0 to 2 loop
                        queue3(i + 1) <= queue3(i);
                    end loop;
                    queue3(0) <= DATA_IN_D;
                   --if(ptr3<=3)then ptr3 <= ptr3 + 1;  end if;
                   ptr3 <= ptr3 + 1;
              END IF;
            elsif(enl = '1')then
                   SendPackage <= '0';
                   --if(step = 0) then step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 1) then TX <= temp(1 downto 0); i_b <= '1'; step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 2) then TX <= temp(3 downto 2);   i_b <= '0'; step <= step + 1;   end if;   --step <= step + 1;
                   if(step = 3) then TX <= temp(5 downto 4); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 4) then TX <= temp(7 downto 6); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 5) then TX <= temp(9 downto 8); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 6) then TX <= temp(11 downto 10); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 7) then TX <= temp(13 downto 12); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 8) then TX <= temp(15 downto 14); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 9) then TX <= temp(17 downto 16); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 10) then TX <= temp(19 downto 18); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 11) then TX <= temp(21 downto 20); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 12) then TX <= temp(23 downto 22); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 13) then TX <= temp(25 downto 24);  step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 14) then TX <= temp(27 downto 26); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 15) then TX <= temp(29 downto 28); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 16) then--mai merg un pas pentru a putea transmite tot pachetul. Daca nu pierd 2 biti
                        TX <= temp(31 downto 30); step <= step + 1;   end if;
                   if(step = 17) then--dupa inca un pas initializez alta trasmitere
                        --step := 0;
                        --temp := X"00000000";
                        --enl := '0';
                        step <= 1;
                        temp <= X"00000000";
                        enl <= '0';
                        --step <= step + 1;
                   end if;
                   i_a <= '1';
                   --step <= step + 1;
            elsif(enl = '0')then
                if(nr = 0)then
                   if(ptr>=1)then
                        ptr <= ptr - 1;
                        --temp := queue(ptr-1);
                        temp <= queue(ptr-1);
                        q_a <= queue(ptr-1);
                        SendPackage <= '1';
                        enl <= '1';
                        step <= 1;
                        --enl := '1';
                        --step := 0;
                        TX <= "00";
                   end if;
                   nr <= nr + 1;
               end if;
               if(nr = 1)then
                   if(ptr1>=1)then
                        ptr1 <= ptr1 - 1;
                        temp <= queue1(ptr1-1);
                        q_b <= queue1(ptr1-1);
                        --temp := queue1(ptr1-1);
                        SendPackage <= '1';
                         enl <= '1';
                        step <= 1;
                        --enl := '1';
                        --step := 0;
                        TX <= "00";
                   end if;
                   nr <= nr + 1;
               end if;
               if(nr = 2)then
                   if(ptr2>=1)then
                        ptr2 <= ptr2 - 1;
                        --temp := queue2(ptr2-1);
                        temp <= queue2(ptr2-1);
                        q_c <= queue2(ptr2-1);
                        SendPackage <= '1';
                         enl <= '1';
                        step <= 1;
                        --enl := '1';
                        --step := 0;
                        TX <= "00";
                   end if;
                   nr <= nr + 1;
               end if;
               if(nr >= 3)then
                   if(ptr3>=1)then
                        ptr3 <= ptr3 - 1;
                        temp <= queue3(ptr3-1);
                        q_d <= queue3(ptr3-1);
                        --temp := queue3(ptr3-1);
                        SendPackage <= '1';
                         enl <= '1';
                        step <= 1;
                        nr <= nr  + 1;
                       -- nr := 0;
                        --enl := '1';
                        --step := 0;
                        TX <= "00";
                   end if;
                   nr <= 0;
                end if;
                --if(nr >= 3 )then nr <= 0; end if;
            end if;

          else
            SendPackage <= '0';
            i_a <= '0';
          end if;
         end if;
          if(ptr >= 4)then fifo_full1 <= '1'; else fifo_full1 <= '0'; end if;
          if(ptr1 >= 4)then fifo_full2 <= '1'; else fifo_full2 <= '0'; end if;
          if(ptr2 >= 4)then fifo_full3 <= '1'; else fifo_full3 <= '0'; end if;
          if(ptr3 >= 4)then fifo_full4 <= '1'; else fifo_full4 <= '0'; end if;
     end process;
end rtl;
```

It works fine until you want to insert data into one queue that is not full and the transmission is running. That step is omitted. Because of that the transmission will not work. I want it to work independently.

ex :

```
step : 1       3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12 ... 17
           _
We   :____| |_____________________________________.....
       _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _    
CLK  :| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_|..
```

I work (simulate and implement on fpga) with Altium Designer Winter 09

Comment: -1 As @Martin points out, posting large chunks of code will usually not get you a good response. Try to write better snippets: http://www.sigasi.com/content/get-better-feedback-your-vhdl-code-snippets

Answer (score 6):

I see you've had little response... You've posted a whole lot of code to expect potential answerers to trawl through!  You'll have to break it down a little before you get much more help I think.  (And tidy it up - eg. remove all the commented out parts please.)

To debug yourself, I'd suggest that you first get a single channel working in an entity of its own.  If you are still having problems, edit your question to state what you've tried, and what didn't work.

Once one channel works, you can instantiate 4 of them with a smaller control process to sort out the loading of those elements and getting the right outputs to the right places.

Build things up in small stages.

**Some comments on your coding style:**

*NB: These are based purely on "style-analysis", not attempting to fix (or indeed  replicate) any functionality!*

---

First off, drop these two clauses

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

You aren't using them.  If you need to do arithmetic on vectors, [use `ieee.numeric_std` and use `unsigned`/`signed` types.](http://parallelpoints.com/node/3)

---

In the `entity`, you have 4 "versions" of several signals - why not make them `std_logic_vector`s with the width of the vectors controlled by  a `generic`?  You could do a similar thing with `ptr`, `ptr1` etc. (make an array of integers - full marks BTW for using `integers` and not trying to make all the arithmetic happen on `std_logic_vectors`)

---

The sensitivity list is too complicated:

```
process(CLK, RESET, We1, We2, We3, We4, DATA_IN_A, DATA_IN_B, DATA_IN_C, DATA_IN_D) is
```

You are writing a synchronous process with an asynchronous reset, so you only need `CLK` and `RESET` in the sensitivity list.

---

Your clock conditions:

```
if (CLK'event) then
     if (CLK = '1') then
```

have a more conventional idiom:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
```

(and no `()`s required around the `if`'s boolean condition. That'd be C programming :)

---

This loop

```
 for i in 0 to 2 loop
     queue(i + 1) <= queue(i);
 end loop;
 queue(0) <= DATA_IN_A;
```

can be done in a single line:

```
queue <= data_in_a & queue(0 to sr_length'high-1);
```

---

Any time lots of code is copied and pasted, there's usually a better way:

```
 if(step = 1) then TX <= temp(1 downto 0); i_b <= '1'; step <= step + 1;   end if;
 if(step = 2) then TX <= temp(3 downto 2);   i_b <= '0'; step <= step + 1;   end if;   
 if(step = 3) then TX <= temp(5 downto 4); step <= step + 1;   end if;
```

could become for example:

```
if (step < 17) then 
    TX <= temp((step-1)*2+1 downto (step-1)*2);
    step <= step + 1;
end if;
i_b <= '0';
if step = 1 then 
   i_b <= '1';
end if;
```

which would be even tidier if step went from 0 to 16 not 1 to 17!

---

Finally, these parts:

```
if(nr = 0)then
  if(ptr>=1)then
```

could be done in a `for` loop if `ptr...`, `q_a`, `q_b`,  etc. were arrays.

and a similar loop for

```
if(ptr >= 4)then fifo_full1 <= '1'; else fifo_full1 <= '0'; end if;
```

Any time you've copied, pasted and then tweaked large chunks of code, look to `loop`, or create a `function` or `procedure` to encapsulate the repeated code.

Comment: `(and no ()s required around the if's boolean condition. That'd be C programming :)` couldn't help but think of [this cartoon](http://xkcd.com/541/) :)

Comment: Thank's for the advices. I wrote the 1 to 17 instead of 0 to 16 because I was losing the data when the ptr = 0. I loke to code with "()" biceuse I cand read the code better. I am just at the begining. Thanks again :0